# How to terminate object in cocoa touch? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I create a button or image dynamically in cocoa touch. I want remove from my FORM and Memory, when I don't want it.

I want to remove completely from Memory and create again when I need it. How do it?

Answer (score 2):

Really too vague to answer but

```
[button removeFromSuperview];
```

may be what you're after.

Comment: thx a lot , dont need [button release] OR self.button = nil?  and i have another question! how to remove Object that make from Class ?

Comment: if you create autorelease instance of any class when you remove it from superview or when it is not needed it will be released automatically. you don't need to release it manually.

Comment: No way to answer that, there's not enough context. Did you autorelease it when you made it and added it to its superview?